# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "​" and array question

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a foreach function where a number in a table in phpmyadmin will increase each time value inside an array matches the "pet_id". And also this only execute whenever a submit button is pressed. This is my code in php file:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
        if (isset($cart)) {
            // if product appeared
            foreach ($product->getData('cart') as $item):
                $cart = $product->getProduct($item['pet_id']);
                $subTotal[] = array_map(function ($item){
                    $sql = "UPDATE pet_info SET number_sold = number_sold + 1 WHERE 
                    $item == pet_info.pet_id;";

                    $query1 = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
                    while ($pet_id = mysqli_fetch_array($query1)) {
                        execute($pet_id['pet_id']); 
                    }
                }); 
            endforeach;
        }   
    }​
?>
```

But I spent the last 2 hours searching for a solution but what i achieve is still errors:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "​" in C:\xampp\htdocs\testing\petsonthenet\partial\_checkout.php:121 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\testing\petsonthenet\user_cart.php(7): include() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\testing\petsonthenet\partial\_checkout.php on line 121
```

Can someone help me please? I'd be very appreciated!!

This is the part of the code related to the cart

```
                <?php
                foreach ($product->getData('cart') as $item) :
                    $cart = $product->getProduct($item['pet_id']);
                    echo gettype($item);
                    $subTotal[] = array_map(function ($item){
            ?>
            <!-- cart item -->
            <div class="row border-top py-3 mt-3">
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <img src="<?php echo $item['image'] ?? "./images/pet (1).jpg" ?>" style="height: 150px; width:120px;" alt="cart1" class="img-fluid">
                </div>
                
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <h5 class="font-baloo font-size-20"><?php echo $item['name'] ?? "Unknown"; ?></h5>
                    <h5 class="font-baloo font-size-20"><?php echo $item['pet_id'] ?? "Unknown"; ?></h5>
                    <small> <?php echo $item['breed'] ?? "Brand"; ?></small>
                        
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-2 text">
                    <div class="font-size-20 text-danger font-baloo">
                        $<span class="product_price" data-id="<?php echo $item['pet_id'] ?? '0'; ?>"><?php echo $item['price'] ?? 0; ?></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <form method="post">
                            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $item['pet_id'] ?? 0; ?>" name="pet_id">
                            <button type="submit" name="delete-cart-submit" class="btn font-baloo text-danger px-3 border-right">Delete</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <!-- !cart item -->
            <?php
                        return $item['price'];
                    }, $cart); // closing array_map function
                endforeach;
            ?>
```

Comment: are you sure the "pet_id" field in the "cart" table always has a valid value?

Comment: The code you shared is relatively small. Can you indicate which line is the line 121 from `_checkout.php` the error refers to?

Comment: @HenryTrần  yes, it already had some integers in each row of the table

Comment: Looks like you have an error in your sql: `$sql = "UPDATE pet_info SET number_sold = number_sold + 1 WHERE $item == pet_info.pet_id;";` Does `$sql = "UPDATE pet_info SET number_sold = number_sold + 1 WHERE $item = pet_info.pet_id;";` work? (Notice the  single `=` sign.) And is __$item__ in integer?

Comment: Also, `array_map` requires two arguments: the function to perform on each item in the array, and the array containing the items. You are currently only giving it the function.

Comment: @rickdenhaan the line 121 is the closing bracket for the whole big if statement

Comment: You can share file ```_checkout.php```?? or at least part of the code around line 121.

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles about the sql query then i'm not so sure but i think if it's wrong then it would give me a different error type. and about $item then it's an array (i just checked it)

Comment: @rickdenhaan oh yeah i forgot. I put in both $cart and $item but still have the same error

Comment: @HenryTrần i just posted it, hope it helps you figure out something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just did a check on your error message, there was a unicode character that didn't display correctly in it, in quotes.
So I determined this was a "typo", if I'm not mistaken you are using mac or linux, and open the Vietnamese typewriter.

You can paste the error message into your browser's javascript console. You will see the error character.

Comment: no actually I'm using Windows and I've checked 5 times within those lines of code and saw no Vietnamese typo. But I will check on the JS console like you've said

Comment: Is it Unikey error? Be very careful with unicode characters other than quotes.

Comment: I suggest you try deleting some code segments and running again. Try this until you get no errors. These help you to find the actual error.

Comment: i'll end the Unicode program and try to write this again

Comment: well, I've rewritten it and there is no error text appeared so this should mean that it worked, I just need to correct my query then it should be perfect. Thank you so much man

Comment: hehe, congrats my friend. from Vietnam, with love.

Answer (score 1):

You have a [zero width space](https://unicodemap.org/details/0x200B/index.html), particularly `<0x200b>` (invisible in a simple text editor), after the last curly brace:

```
...
            endforeach;
        }   
    }​  //<-- here
?>
```

[image]

This appears to be an undefined [constant](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.syntax.php) to PHP.

Delete what is after that last curly brace.

Comment: Remember to fix your `array_map` and sql query.

Comment: In my vscode, there is no blank space after the curly brace. I try bolding but still have nothing

Comment: Delete the entire line and retype the closing curly brace.

Comment: paste your user_cart.php into browser's devtools console. Find red-dot and remove it. take back your code.

Comment: yeah I think it must be the case. Thank you so much man